# Recursive mocking Outlook.Interop interface with Moq throws "Invalid Operation Exception"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, outlook, moq, office-interop

I try to test my Outlook Addin but i have Problems to Mock the Object.
I'm using Moq and I want to test if the count of Recipients is 0. 
This is the Code:

```
[TestMethod]      
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void CheckValidMail_ZeroRecipientens()
{                  
    var mock = new Mock<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>();
    //In this line i get the Exception
    mock.Setup(b => b.Recipients.Count).Returns(0);
    // I also tried this one
    //mock.SetupProperty(x => x.Recipients.Count, 0);         
    var  t = mock.Object;               
    var mailconverter = new MailConverter(t);          
    mailconverter.CheckValidMail();

}
```

Then I get this Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The variable" x "of type"
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem "is referenced by the range"
>   ", but it is not defined."

This is the `Mailconverter` Class

```
public class MailConverter
{
    private Outlook.MailItem mail;

    public MailConverter(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
    {
        this.mail = mailItem;
    }

    public void CheckValidMail()
    {
        CheckRecipientsCount();            
    }

    private void CheckRecipientsCount()
    {
        if (mail.Recipients.Count == 0) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Min 1 Recipient");
        else if (mail.Recipients.Count > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Max 1 Recipient");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you get that exception. Can you show the subject of the test `MailConverter` and `CheckValidMail()`

Comment: I added the MailConverter Class + Marked the line where i get the Exception

Comment: Weird! Also note that if you use the mock `var mock = new Mock<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem> { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock, };` instead, and do no setups at all, then `mock.Object.Recipients.Count` will return the default value `0`. However, this is not useful when you want to test a count which is `> 1` or `== 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for posts with similar error messages it looks like the error is associated with conflicting parameter names during the creation/construction of lambda expressions.

I believe it had to do with the framework trying to recursive mock the setup of

```
mock.Setup(b => b.Recipients.Count).Returns(0);
```

Somehow the mocking framework was failing to recursive mock the `Count` property as it conflicted with something when wrapping the `Recipients` property.

I am uncertain if the issue stems from the interop interfaces themselves, but Mocking each interface separately worked when tested.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void CheckValidMail_ZeroRecipientens() {
    //Arrange
    var mockRecpients = new Mock<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients>();
    mockRecpients.Setup(_ => _.Count).Returns(0);
    var mockMailItem = new Mock<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>();
    mockMailItem.Setup(_ => _.Recipients).Returns(mockRecpients.Object);
    var mailItem = mockMailItem.Object;
    var mailconverter = new MailConverter(mailItem);

    //Act
    mailconverter.CheckValidMail();
}
```

Comment: While I find this post good, it would be nice to find the specific reason for the problem. The workaround is OK, but what is so special about the original expression tree `b => b.Recipients.Count`. If I make my own public interfaces with equivalent property "design", the expression `b => b.Recipients.Count` (where `b` is my interface) works fine.